# Node js TypeScript, can not find module src/

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am having problems with non-relative imports in node js / typescript app.

This is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I am having the following hierarchy of [image: files].

In  the file src/resolvers/usersResolver/helpers/userLogin.ts
I am making an import of the User model in the following way.

```
import { User } from "entity/User";
```

And the ts lint is fine with that, but when I run the dist version I am getting  this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'entity/User'
```

But If I make relative imports such that ../../entity/User it works fine.

I was trying to change baseUrl from . -> src and so on, nothing really helped.

Answer (score 0):

The baseUrl configuration is for how your compiled js is handled, not how the TS compiler is handling your file paths. You'll need to fully qualify your paths from the projects root directory, or use relative paths like in your example you said works `../../entity/User`

Now, with that being said, there are plenty of tools that help auto complete and change paths as files move so these are easier to manage.

By not specifying the full or relative path, the compiler is trying to look in your node_modules to find a `entity/User` package.

Comment: Okay, so the thing is that when I want to use auto improt in vs code it actually does src/entity/User and it does not work so I need to rewrite it.
Is there any way to tell make relative imports then ?

Answer (score 0):

Install tspath an npm tool for resolving ts paths NOTE: tspath requires a very recent versison of node!

```
npm install -g tspath
```

After you have run the TypeScript compiler, from your project directory, run:

```
tspath
```

or

tspath -f
to skip the prompt!